# How not to use the container within Laravel controller method?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have started to look at Laravel and I have some doubts about the management of dependencies within my project. Let's say I have a dependency 
`DependencyA` which uses `DependencyB` which uses `DependencyC`:

```
<?php 

namespace Some\NamespaceOf;

use Illuminate\Container\Container;

class DependencyA {

   public function someMethod(DependencyB $b, Container $container) {
      $container->call([$b, 'doSomething']);
   }

}

class DependencyB {
   public function doSomething(DependencyC $c) {
      // ... do something with $c
   } 
}
```

Then, within my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Some\NamespaceOf\DependencyA;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @param DependencyA  $a
     * @return Response
     */
    public function controllerMethod(DependencyA $a, Container $container)
    {
        $container->call([$a, 'someMethod']);
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

I do not like passing the controller over and over between my components.

What is the best refactoring in this case? Rewriting the controller to:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Some\NamespaceOf\DependencyA;
use Some\NamespaceOf\DependencyB;
use Illuminate\Container\Container;

class SomeController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @param DependencyA  $a
     * @return Response
     */
    public function controllerMethod(DependencyA $a, DependencyB $b)
    {
        $a->someMethod($b);
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Would not be enough since `DependencyA` also needs the container to lookup `DependencyC` before calling `$b->doSomething()` passing it `$c`. I would have to edit `DependencyA` too, but how can I inject `DependencyC` to it then?

What should be done when these kind of dependencies form?
Using a container within a component makes me think that the `IoC` principle gets violated.

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Try not to send your dependencies as parameters.

Comment: I think that's the only way, isn't it. But then I feel like I am loosing "semantics", but maybe it's just merely a wrong conclusion I do on which I do not have to focus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you; this might be helpful:

The **AppServiceProvider**:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Dependencies\DependencyA;
use App\Dependencies\DependencyB;
use App\Dependencies\DependencyC;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(DependencyB::class, function ($app) {
            return new DependencyB(new DependencyC());
        });

        $this->app->bind(DependencyA::class, function ($app) {
            return new DependencyA($app->make(DependencyB::class));
        });
    }
}
```

**DependencyA**:

```
namespace App\Dependencies;

class DependencyA
{
    private $dependencyB;

    public function __construct(DependencyB $dependencyB)
    {
        $this->dependencyB = $dependencyB;
    }

    public function useMe()
    {
        return $this->dependencyB->useMe();
    }
}
```

**DependencyB**:

```
namespace App\Dependencies;

class DependencyB
{
    private $dependencyC;

    public function __construct(DependencyC $dependencyC)
    {
        $this->dependencyC = $dependencyC;
    }

    public function useMe()
    {
        return $this->dependencyC->useMe();
    }
}
```

**DependencyC**:

```
namespace App\Dependencies;

class DependencyC
{
    public function useMe()
    {
        echo "Used me.";
    }
}
```

Now, In our controller, If we use DependencyA as the only dependency; the dependency of DependencyA class and The DependencyB class will be resolved respectively.

**DependantController**:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Dependencies\DependencyA;

class DependantController extends Controller
{
    private $dependencyA;

    public function __construct(DependencyA $dependencyA)
    {
        $this->dependencyA = $dependencyA;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->dependencyA->useMe();
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('dependant', 'DependantController@index');
```

Now, if you visit e.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dependant` you will see `Used me.` as the result of this implementation.

Comment: So basically the rule is not to create methods with type hinted parameters, but to type hint the constructor instead... Right?

Comment: This is not about where you type hint. If you provide DepA as the parameter of the index action, Laravel will behave the same. But the context of the dependency will be limited to index. This might even increase your application performance depending on your arthitecture. My approach to the problem presented above is called Automatic Injection. However, if it is needed to change the dependency on runtime and the conditional binding is not the solution; passing the manually resolved dependencies might be an option. Let's name this solution a good practice. You know, there is no silver bullet.